# Parsing JSON with PHP and displaying contents

Tags: php, html, json

I am having issues with this code

This is my PHP that worked with other projects...

```
$gas = file_get_contents('http://api.mygasfeed.com/stations/loadbygeo/47.9494949/120.23423432/reg|mid|pre|diesel/'. $api . '.json?callback=?');



$json_output = json_decode(utf8_decode($gas));

$location= $json_output->geoLocation->city_id;
```

This is the JSON result

```
?({"status":{"error":"NO","code":200,"description":"none","message":"Request    ok"},"geoLocation":{"city_id":"13123","city_long":"Hulunber","region_short":"Nei Mongol","region_long":"Nei Mongol","country_long":"China","country_id":"49","region_id":"6010"},"stations":[]})
```

This code is returning a blank result.

Comment: That's not JSON. That's JSONP. you need to unwrap the function call before decoding.

Comment: Could you clarify?  The URL does not use jsonp

Comment: @DavidMorin: Yes, it does. Try `?callback=` instead of `?callback=?`.

Comment: I tried removing the ? and i still get nothing. blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `?(` and the `)`.  See [WP:JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

One could use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) for that, or better yet a regex to assert and remove only the desired garbage:

```
$json = preg_replace("/ ^[?\w(]+ | [)]+\s*$ /x", "", $jsonp);
```

Would remove arbitrary `callbackFnNames(` but also your strange `?(` pseudo function call.

Comment: $gas = file_get_contents('http://api.mygasfeed.com/stations/loadbygeo/42.364632/-71.059227/reg|mid|pre|diesel/'. $api . '.json?callback=');

$parsed_json = json_decode($gas);
$rest = substr("' . $parsed_json . '", 1, -1); 
$location = $rest->{'geoLocation'}->{'city_id'};


print $location;

Comment: Mentioned before: "You need to unwrap the function call **before** decoding".

Comment: sorry i guess im not sure how to do this... could you help me? show me where to find this document?